# Two-Way Lookup to return exact match or next smallest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a two-way lookup of a matrix table when given two criteria:

1. Year
2. Value

Since the table is basically just a range of values per year, I need to apply either:

1. Exact match
   or
2. If no exact match is found, round down and select the nearest lower value

And once that is complete, return the category.

See below for a truncated sample of the table:

Row 1 contains the years going back to 1998.
Beneath the year, are the values themselves.

And Column A contains the category (1-16) that I need to return.

[image]

And this is the data given:

[image]

Initial ask was to do exact match or find closest match (either up or down) and return the corresponding category. And this was working for me.

```
=LET(y,ABS(FILTER(B$2:J$10,B$1:J$1=A14)-B14),INDEX(A$2:A$10,XMATCH(MIN(y),y,,-1)))
```

However, the requirements are now changing to exact match or else round down.

How would I go about resolving this?

Comment: Why not do it in this way, instead of the one you are using `ABS()` etc. --> `=XLOOKUP(B14,FILTER(B$2:J$10,B$1:J$1=A14),A$2:A$10,,-1)` if i am not wrong or mistaken here, Can you explain further

Comment: -1 as criteria for XMATCH should pick exact or closest smaller value. I was trying with an index match with a filter but I'm not as accustomed to interweaving filter results yet, @MayukhBhattacharya got the right answer here.

Comment: @Notus_Panda with `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` function it would be certainly like this --> `=LET(y,FILTER(B$2:J$10,B$1:J$1=A14),INDEX(A$2:A$10,MATCH(1,1/(y<=M2),0)))` but i opted for `XLOOKUP()` because its more versatile than the earlier.

Comment: Ah, that's why I had #N/A, my Match was set up wrong, I was thinking of using the last criteria as "1" (and just searching for the value, not like a "TRUE" search) but it's not in an ascending order (just re-read the documentation) so that wouldn't work. @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your comment, but in this scenario it would work, not only and but there are others i see, who have used this approach earlier for resolving a scenario like this. Also what i see its a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your data from top to bottom is sorted descending. If yes, 2 `XLOOKUP`'s would work:

```
=XLOOKUP(B11,XLOOKUP(A11,$B$1:$G$1,$B$2:$G$7,,0),$A$2:$A$7,,-1)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following formula, with <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> & <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(M2,FILTER($B$2:$J$10,L2=$B$1:$J$1),$A$2:$A$10,,-1)
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down, perhaps you can spill with one single dynamic array formula as below using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=MAP(L2:L4,M2:M4,LAMBDA(α,σ,XLOOKUP(σ,FILTER(B2:J10,α=B1:J1),A2:A10,,-1)))
```

---

With <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> function, it would be like this.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N2</kbd>

```
=LET(y,FILTER(B$2:J$7,L2=B$1:J$1),INDEX(A$2:A$7,MATCH(1,1/(y<=M2),0)))
```

---

With one single dynamic array formula:

[image]

---

```
=MAP(L2:L4,M2:M4,LAMBDA(α,ß,INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(1,1/(FILTER(B2:J7,α=B1:J1)<=ß),0))))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

I think @MayukhBhattacharya's answer is what you are looking for and his answer is pretty complete and dynamic, but just in case you need Excel *old school* formulas it would be like this:

[image]

Formula in cell C18 is:

```
    =INDEX($A$2:$A$11;MATCH(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($B$2:$J$11<=B18)*--($B$1:$J$1=A18)*$B$2:$J$11));INDEX($B$2:$J$11;;MATCH(A18;$B$1:$J$1;0));0))
```